# Twig create array and place them in specific places

Tags: arrays, twig

I'm pretty new to Twig and can't figure one thing out!

I'm trying to create a homepage where in different spots images need to be placed. I know this can be done by executing a function where an image need to be placed. Problem is that I have to do that 7 times on one page.

So my question is if you can create some sort of array and then get the results from the array in the appropiate spots.

See below

[image]

Let's say I want to place an image in A,D,E,G. What would be the quickest way to accomplish that? What I already can do is

```
 {% for product in products %}

 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are your layouts fixed? Are the place of images in your layouts variable? What exactly have you done yet (the provided code does not really help)?

Comment: @Javad: Thx for your reply. I actually found an answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869896/how-to-get-the-second-element-in-a-for-loop/23871492#23871492