# How to get the second element in a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, twig

I have a for loop in Twig. I'm trying to access different elements in a for loop so I can use them in different places on my website.

Let'say I have a template called 'images'. Inside that template I have a for loop like so:

```
{% for image in images %}
<div>
  <img src="{{ image | url_image }}" width="100" height="100" />
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

In a different template I'm trying to include this 'images' template. So what I have is this:

```
{% include 'images.html' %}
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that I only want the second element from the for loop in the images.html template. How do you do that?

So I want something like this:

```
<div>
{% include 'images.html' with {'second element'} only %}
</div>
```

Does anyone know what the best approach is or how do you do that? I'm pretty new to Twig as you can see ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost already found your answer!

Use the [for with condition](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition) syntax:

```
{% for key,image in images if key==elementNumber %}
<div>
  <img src="{{ image | url_image }}" width="100" height="100" />
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And call you template with the parameter's value you need (keeping in mind that `key` starts at 0, so the example bellow will give you the second element):

```
<div>
{% include 'images.html' with {elementNumber: 1} %}
</div>
```

This syntax is useful if you want to do some "elaborated" things like `if key<elementNumber`

But if you need only one element at a time, this might be better, instead of the for loop:

```
<div>
  <img src="{{ images[elementNumber] | url_image }}" width="100" height="100" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thx this worked perfectly. Learned something new today!